# ListFragment with ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-listfragment

I have create List Fragment that has cursor adapter , now i need to categorize the result to be something like expandable list.
i tried to add the list fragment inside expandable list , but it didn't work.
can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the design that you want to achieve. Rough design will suffice

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing so, create a layout with that `ExpandableListView`, like this:

**expandedlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExpandableListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Pay attention to the `android:id` for this view. This is the way `ListFragment` can link to it without worrying. Then, add this method into your `ListFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandedlist, null);
    return view;
}
```

Now, this precise view you are inflating is an `ExpandableListView`. You could also save that view into a class field, to let if available accross.

Comment: my listfragment already has inflated layout
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container,
    false);

Comment: And is that list an `ExpandableListView`? So what's the problem, actually? Could you edit your answer and add some extra code, like that layout, please?